# Is there an arg to set other endpoint in start_http_server (prometheus_client) instead of /?

Tags: python, flask, instrumentation, prometheus

I'm building a Flask application and I would like to know if there is an arg on module `start_http_server` (from prometheus_client) that allow me to set a specific metrics endpoint instead /.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Prometheus client with flask, you don't need to start the http server on your own but you can enable the wsgi middleware and specify the route you want to serve your metrics on your existing app.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app_dispatch = DispatcherMiddleware(app, {
  '/metrics': make_wsgi_app()
})
```

For the full example how to do this, just check out the [python prometheus_client docs on flask](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#flask).